# Cannot Import OBJ MTL and texture files into Cinema 4d

Tags: object, 3d, cinema-4d, mtl-file

I have a model to import into Cinema 4d
In the directory, there are two files OBJ and MTL with a single folder which holds texture image files JPG and PNG etc.

I open OBJ file in Cinema 4d, and then I can view Model without material applied on objects. I tried to apply material from script menu **script >> User Scripts >> Run Script..**
and it shows **Unknown file format** error.
What I am missing here?

Comment: Files are created with blender

Comment: there were some limitations in Cinema 4D because 3D model was originally created with licensed Cinema 4D, and my Cinema 4d instance was limited. I was trying various workarounds, thanks